# jQuery append content increase

Tags: jquery, append

Here is a sample code:

```
var i1 = $("<a>content1</a>");
var i2 = $("<a>content2</a>");
var i3 = $("<a>content3</a>");
var i4 = $("<a>content4</a>");
var i5 = $("<a>content5</a>");
b.append(i1);
```

This is the desired effect:

1. When the first +1 button is clicked, b.append(i1) should be called and content1 shown;
2. When the second +1 button is clicked, b.append(i2) should be called and content2 shown;
3. When the third+1 button is clicked, b.append(i3) should be called and content3 shown;
4. When the fourth +1 button is clicked, b.append(i4) should be called and content4 shown;
5. When the fifth +1 button is clicked, b.append(i5) should be called and content5 shown;

So far this is what I have been able to achieve: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/2/)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: than what is the problem ?????????????

Comment: If you are writing variables which end with a number, generally you're doing it wrong.

Comment: look this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/7/

Since you are having a count in `cur` variable, it can be used with `eval()` function as follows :

```
b.append(eval('i' + cur));
```

For removing :

```
var index = c.attr("value").replace("-","");
(eval('i' + (index))).remove();
```

Comment: thanks my man, http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/11/  look this, If you press a few +1 button, i want remove some them, Also followed changes in the amount of content

Comment: @DongYifei , See if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/14/) is what you want..

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want..

added a `var clickedcount` in your codes , used `switch()` and likewise displayed the content..

you don't need different variable .. i managed it with the same variable `i1`

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/3/)..

Comment: yea, this look so good, but i want just only one content, like only content1, or content2  http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/6/

Comment: help me fix this, i need just only one content. http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/6/

Comment: try this fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/9/

Comment: updated the fiddle.. check the fiddle in previous comment